# Jumping to a HTML element in a SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

When I need the user to jump to a specific element in HTML, I'd normally just pass a hashtag in the URL, but in this instance it's a single page application (like AngularJS) and so hashtags are used to load views.

I have jQuery, but I can't figure out how to jump down to a specific element in the view when the user returns to it.

I've tried:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".gallery .selected").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

And even a simple:

```
var scrollPos = $(".gallery .selected").scrollTop();
$('html,body').scrollTop(scrollPos);
```

`console.log(scrollPos)` is always 0, and even `scrollTop(500)` doesn't move the scrollbar. Argh.

But it doesn't move at all. (I'm wondering if it can see the element.)

Comment: how many `.selected` elements do you have? if more than one, then which one do you wanna jump to?

Comment: If you're in a SPA just relax! Just kidding, do you have a test page? You say "like AngularJS". Is it Angular or is it something else?

Comment: I always only have one element that matches ".gallery .selected".

Comment: Have you checked if your element to move has css position: absolute applied?

Comment: @JonasGrumann It's something else (a bespoke system by the previous developer).

Comment: check the output of `$(".gallery .selected").offset().top` and let us know

Comment: @AminJafari Thanks. It's returning 0 -- it clearly can't see the element in question. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

it depends which mvc framework you are using to create your spa if you are using angular you may be better of using an angular specific command i.e. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll other frameworks may have other methods

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
function _ease(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts = (t /= d) * t;
    var tc = ts * t;
    return b + c * (-1 * ts * ts + 4 * tc + -6 * ts + 4 * t);
};

HTMLElement.prototype.scrollTopTo = function(a, f) {
    var b = this.scrollTop, g = a - b, c = 0, d = a < b ? Math.abs(b - a) << 1 : Math.abs(a - b) << 1, h = this, e = function() {
        c += 20;
        var a = _ease(c, b, g, d);
        h.scrollTop = a;
        c < d ? setTimeout(e, 20) : f();
    };
    e();
};
HTMLElement.prototype.scrollTopToChild = function(el, callback) {
    var bodyRect = this.getBoundingClientRect(), elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.scrollTopTo(elRect.top - bodyRect.top, callback);
};
```

Hope this helps.
to call:

```
document.body.scrollTopToChild(document.getElementById('scrollToMe'),function() {alert('done')});
```